# DNS / VPS / SSL

Tags: email, dns, ssl, gmail

In dire need of help. My head is spinning and my experience limited.

I have a VPS with Hostinger, domains dns with GoDaddy.

Emails were working until I realised gmail was an issue as no reverse DNS, Since then following Hostingers advice, my dns is under the control of GoDaddy and I thought it was working till I tried to install SpamAssasin which failed and I had to uninstall.

Between GoDaddy and Hostinger I have read and followed their advice and its got worse and worse till I no longer know which way is up. I wont write more till I know what information is required but I would be very grateful for some knowledgeable guidance before I tear my hair out.

My 'host' site with Hostinger is [www.spirita.net](http://www.spirita.net) and I also use email on [www.spirita.co.uk](http://www.spirita.co.uk) with mail servers for each.I only use personal email, no marketing of any kind.

At the moment nothing appears to be getting in and my emails sometimes arrive at the other end but replies dont come back. I need to check dns setting and ssl.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot continue to try advice from random posts found by hostinger/godaddys tech support.

I need to go back to basics and check everything starting with dns settings then ssl requirements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The good news is that the IP -> DNS resolution thing for your domains is correct. I checked and reverse DNS matches forward DNS, so you are "good to go" on that count.

Comment: When I try and telnet to 93.188.167.153 on port 25 I am not getting a banner.  This means that your SMTP server is not correctly set up and listening to requests from the world.  That is at least part of the reason you are not receiving emails and the first thing you need to sort out.   Check that your SMTP server is running, and also that its not only bound to "localhost" - but be careful to ensure its not an open relay.   (Interestingly port 110 and 993 are open, so the POP/IMAP side of things is at least running).

Comment: Many thanks, trying to follow Hostingers directions for changing port - not working so far but will get back with results

Comment: I have switched to port 25 and its open but still nothing coming in or out with the exception of email sent from spirita.net to another email at spirita.net. I am  out of my depth here. Any suggestions what to look at next?